# Btrfs local Snapshots vs Incremental remote Backup

Tags: backup, nas, btrfs, snapshot, incremental-backup

In a NAS context, I'm wondering about the pros of btrfs local snapshots when incremental remote backup is made on a remote server.
I'm also wondering about the interest to have both snapshots and backup enabled at the same time.

Incremental remote backup allows the following:

- restore data in case of disk failure
- restore data in case of ransomware
- restore data in case of "damned I should not have deleted this file 6 months ago!"
- "Damned my house just burnt, oh great news I still have my data somewhere to access from my tent under the bridge"

Btrfs local snapshot:

- restore data in case of ranswomware (only if immutable which can bring inconvenience in regards of free space management)
- restore data in case of "damned I should not have deleted this file 3 days ago! (and I emptied the bin)"

When comparing both I don't see anything snapshots add the list when you already have remote backup enabled. Could anyone confirm there is no real interest in having local snapshots enabled when incremental remote backup is made?